# 4D matrix operations in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, 4d

I have a set of 4D matrices in Matlab. The first three dimensions are spatial, the last is temporal. That means each voxel is a time series. If Img is the 4D image, Img(x,y,z,:) is the time series of voxel with coordinate (x,y,z).

Now I want to normalize (zero mean and unit variance) each time series of the image. How can I do this? Perhaps with `zscore(Img,[],4)`?

Second, I want to concatenate the time series of all images. Let's say Img1, Img2, Img3,....Imgn are the 4D images. For each voxel I want to concatenate the time series over all images so that in the end I have one 4D image with the same spatial but extended temporal dimension. So let's say the voxel has the coordinate (x,y,z), then the concatenated time series would be `[squeeze(Img1(x,y,z,:)); squeeze(Img2(x,y,z,:));....;squeeze(Imgn(x,y,z,:))]`. This should be done for all voxels.

How can I do this? It could be done with for loops but this is not efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First question: normalize

This can be easily done with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Img = bsxfun(@rdivide, Img, std(Img,0,4)); %// unit variance. Or change 0 to 1; see std
Img = bsxfun(@minus, Img, mean(Img,4)); %// zero mean
```

### Second question: concatenate

Just use [`cat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) along the fourth dimension:

```
result = cat(4, Img1, Img2, Img3);
```

It's easier if you have all images in a cell array:

```
cellImgs = {Img1, Img2, Img3};
```

because then you can use a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

```
result = cat(4, cellImgs{:});
```

so the code is independent of the number of images.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed, all my images are in a cell array.